# SASS_PATH not recognized when running "yarn build" in Dockerized create-react-app

Tags: docker, create-react-app

I'm currently developing a CRA app using Docker. Everything is fine in development. However, when I want to create the production build (I'm using a separate docker-compose.yml file for the production build), it keeps telling me it cannot find the files.

I keep getting `Cannot find module: 'lorem.scss'. Make sure this package is installed.` It happens right after `yarn run build` in the building environment.

My Dockerfile:

```
##############################
# Base Image
##############################
# Ger current Node Alpine Linux image.
FROM node:alpine AS base
# Set working directory.
WORKDIR /home/node/app/
# Copy project content.
COPY package.json ./

##############################
# Development Image
##############################
# Development environment.
FROM base AS development
# Run yarn to install.
RUN yarn
# Copy source code.
COPY ./src/ /home/node/app/src/
COPY ./public/ /home/node/app/public/
# Copy Storybook files.
COPY ./stories/ /home/node/app/stories/
COPY ./.storybook/ /home/node/app/.storybook/
# Run the app.
CMD [ "yarn", "run", "dev" ]

##############################
# Building Environment
##############################
# Building environment set.
FROM base AS builder
# Run yarn to install.
RUN yarn
# Copy source code.
COPY ./src/ /home/node/app/src/
COPY ./public/ /home/node/app/public/
# Run the build.
RUN yarn run build

##############################
# Production Image
##############################
FROM nginx:alpine AS production
# Copy source code.
COPY --from=builder /home/node/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
# Copy nginx configuration template.
COPY ./nginx.template /etc/nginx/conf.d/
# Set permissions so nginx can serve it.
RUN chown nginx.nginx /usr/share/nginx/html/ -R
```

My docker-compose.production.yml file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
##############################
# Front-End Container
##############################
  frontend:
    container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}_frontend
    build:
      context: ./frontend/
      target: production
    restart: always
    environment:
      - PROJECT_NAME=${PROJECT_NAME}
      - NODE_PATH=${REACT_NODE_PATH}
      - NODE_PORT=${NODE_PORT}
      - SASS_PATH=${SASS_PATH}
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
    command: /bin/ash -c "envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
    expose:
      - "80"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

My variables in the .env file are as follows:

```
SASS_PATH=node_modules:src/components:src/assets/styles:src/assets/fonts
REACT_NODE_PATH=src/assets/styles/pages:src/assets/images
```

Comment: So your `docker-compose build` is failing? If so please add the complete log output through a pastebin link

Comment: Not docker-compose build. I'm running `docker-compose -f docker-compose.production.yml up`.

Comment: Got it, check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are expecting the environment files to be passed to your docker build. While there is nothing like that happening. The `environment` that you define is only passed to image at run-time as run-time environment.

So you need to either use build arguments or set these environments in your image

**Passing environments**

```
##############################
# Building Environment
##############################
# Building environment set.
FROM base AS builder
# Run yarn to install.
RUN yarn
# Copy source code.
COPY ./src/ /home/node/app/src/
COPY ./public/ /home/node/app/public/
# Run the build.
ENV SASS_PATH=node_modules:src/components:src/assets/styles:src/assets/fonts REACT_NODE_PATH=src/assets/styles/pages:src/assets/images
RUN yarn run build
```

Or you need to use build args

```
##############################
# Building Environment
##############################
# Building environment set.
FROM base AS builder
# Run yarn to install.
RUN yarn
# Copy source code.
COPY ./src/ /home/node/app/src/
COPY ./public/ /home/node/app/public/
# Run the build.
ARG SASS_PATH
ARG REACT_NODE_PATH
ENV SASS_PATH=${SASS_PATH}
ENV REACT_NODE_PATH=${REACT_NODE_PATH}
RUN yarn run build
```

And update your compose file like

```
version: "3.7"
services:
##############################
# Front-End Container
##############################
  frontend:
    container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}_frontend
    build:
      context: ./frontend/
      target: production
      args:
        - REACT_NODE_PATH=${REACT_NODE_PATH}
        - SASS_PATH=${SASS_PATH}
    restart: always
    environment:
      - PROJECT_NAME=${PROJECT_NAME}
      - NODE_PATH=${REACT_NODE_PATH}
      - NODE_PORT=${NODE_PORT}
      - SASS_PATH=${SASS_PATH}
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
    command: /bin/ash -c "envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
    expose:
      - "80"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `development` layer contains

```
CMD [ "yarn", "run", "dev" ]
```

which means that an instance of the final image will run the `dev` script.  You probably want to have something like

```
FROM base AS development
...
ENTRYPOINT [ "yarn", "run" ]
CMD [ "dev" ]

FROM nginx:alpine AS production
...
CMD [ "prod" ]
```

The underlying problem is that you try to stuff both a development image and a production image into the same Dockerfile.

Multistage Dockerfiles are usually used to avoid build utilities taking up space (and enlarging the attack surface) of the production image.  Also, an intermediate layer that runs all the unit/acceptance tests can make sure that no image is produced if the test fails.

If you need a separate development image, see "Stop at a specific build stage" section of [multistage build documentaiton](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).

Comment: I'm so sorry. I copy/pasted the wrong Dockerfile. I'll update immediately.

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer